# Binding input with ngResource get() search with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource, angular-ngmodel

I've a little piece of code that makes a query into a 3rd party API. Is this one:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
function Hello($scope, $http) {

$http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q=alva-noto&page=1&per_page=200').
    success(function(data3) {
        $scope.results = data3.results;
    });

};
```

In the html side, right now I just display a UL with ng-repeat on the li, based in one particular search. Like so:

```
<h1>Search</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="result in results">{{result.title}}</li>
  </ul>
```

My question is, how could I create an input field that binds the text written inside with the search query? Like introducing the string into ?=string:

```
$http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q=string&page=1&per_page=200')
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$scope.$watch` to set a listener to the input variable.

```
<div class="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="result in results">{{result.title}}</li>
  </ul> 
<div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope, $http) {
    var get_results = function(name) {
            $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name + '&page=1&per_page=200').
        success(function(data3) {
            $scope.results = data3.results;
        });
    }
    $scope.name = ''
    $scope.$watch('name', get_results, true);

}
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJgC6/)

Comment: It works brilliantly! Just one more question: In the query I specify type=artist, but in the result I'm getting also releases, and some of them even repeated several times. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks Valeh!

Comment: I observed that if I use the code shown above (not the one in jsfiddle), it only responds with artists, but then the default value even being name='', shows results. If I use the code with the big space from the jsfiddle, the default is empty, but it returns results that are not artists. Any idea for a workaround? Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome! the problem is related to the web service that you use. so you can't solve it in client side.

Comment: What about creating a function that initializes the $watch on ng-click on the input?

Comment: I've created a separate question for the issue, many thanks Valeh!

Comment: Answered your another question too.